# add to favorites (rails 5) returns error (Couldn't find Recipe without an ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need help implementing and adding to a favorites feature in my web app. It's a recipes app where chefs (users) can save other chef's recipes as "favorites".

In the model level I have the following associations:

chef.rb:

```
has_many :favorites
has_many :recipes, through: :favorites
```

recipe.rb:

```
has_many :favorites
has_many :chefs, through: :favorites
```

favorite.rb:

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chef
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

In the migration file I've created a favorites table with:

```
t.integer :chef
t.integer :recipe
t.timestamps
```

In routes.rb:

```
get 'my_favorites', to: 'chefs#my_favorites'
resources :favorites
post 'add_recipe', to: 'recipes#add_recipe'
```

In RecipesController I've defined:

```
def my_favorites
 @favorites = current_chef.recipes
end

def add_recipe
 @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id]) 
 current_chef.favorites.build(recipe_id: @recipe.id)

 if @recipe.save
  redirect_to my_favorites_path, notice: "Favorite recipe was 
                                       successfully added"
 else
  redirect_to my_favorites_path, flash[:error] = "There was an error 
                                 with adding recipe as favorite"
 end
end
```

In views:

I created an "add as my favorite" `link_to` button in views/recipes/show.html.erb file. But when I click it from the browser it returns a error: `Couldn't find Recipe without an ID`.

```
<% if logged_in? %>
 <% if current_chef.not_favorites_with?(@recipe) %>
  <%= link_to "Add as my favorite", add_recipe_path(chef: 
                              current_chef, recipe: @chef), 
                              class: "btn btn-xs btn-success", 
                              method: :post %>
 <% else %>
  <span class="label label-primary">
  It's already your favorite recipe
  </span>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is what's going on in the server:

```
Processing by RecipesController#add_recipe as HTML
 Parameters:    {"authenticity_token"=>"Pz5C/yK0mP5QtONHJs83fhxcrQ6Alvbp2qpPrVOiKdBKyIUys
pww/7L8S66lcOmFGWZr8Lq1ka1rt2D4FbY8NQ==", "chef"=>"9"}
 Chef Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "chefs".* FROM "chefs" WHERE "chefs"."id" 
= ? ORDER BY "chefs"."created_at" DESC LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)  

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Recipe without an ID):
```

I don't know why it cannot grab the recipe's id.

https://github.com/0rdinaryman/myrecipes

Comment: Instead of inventing your own endpoints, it's generally a good idea to adhere to the REST ones to keep things orderly and predictable. `resources :recipes` can have a sub-route `resources: favorites` which creates the route `/recipes/:recipe_id/favorites` you can use to create new favorites with.

Comment: Hi tadman, thanks for your reply. But I'm not sure if you meant this (routes.rb):             
  get 'my_favorites', to: 'chefs#my_favorites'
  resources :favorites
  post 'add_recipe', to: 'recipes#add_recipe'
  get '/recipes/:recipe_id/favorites', to: 'recipes#add_recipe'         
                                                                                                      
  resources :recipes do
    resources :comments, only: [:create]
    member do
      post 'like'
    end
  end

Comment: More like that, yes. Sticking to the general REST model as much as possible. On some occasions you'll have additional actions which you can add to `resources` using a `member` or `collection` block with `get` or `post` declarations. All covered in the [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 1):

In the controller you try to search **Recipe** by `id` but pass as `recipe` in link.
Try to modify link as

```
<%= link_to "Add as my favorite", add_recipe_path(chef: 
                              current_chef, id: @recipe), 
                              class: "btn btn-xs btn-success", 
                              method: :post %>
```

Comment: Hi idej, it returns a new error for that specific line of code: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: What `@chef` should be in this view? Because it's `nil`

Comment: That's because you need to pass the `@recipe` not the `@chef.id`.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Maybe, I'm not sure because haven't see the controller method. Looks like you are right.

Comment: The controller says `def add_recipe; @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe]) ` but also the `show` method doesn't have a `@chef` variable defined: `def show; @comment = Comment.new; @comments = @recipe.comments.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5); end`.